# How about a Gouda soufflé?

Tags: cheese, souffle

I'm a huge fan of Gouda and I've always wondered how it would be going into a cheese soufflé.

But has anyone ever tired it?

All these recipes call for other types of cheese.

Comment: I know this isn't literally a recipe request, since you're asking "do (good) recipes exist?" not "what's a good recipe?" but it's awfully similar. The rest of the question seems to be soliciting opinions, i.e. "will this taste good?" Is there something specific you wanted to know?

Comment: If you change the question to ask broadly what kinds of cheese work in a souffle (hard? soft?), however, with gouda perhaps as an example, that might be a decent question.

Answer (score 1):

When choosing a cheese for soufflés, the standard approach is to choose a (semi-)hard cheese with an assertive flavour - because you typically want the soufflé to *taste cheesy*. So many recipes suggest Gruyère, add a dash of Parmesan or similar.

[Gouda](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gouda_cheese) on the other hand is a surprisingly vague term. It can mean everything from a young, four week old cheese to a mature cheese that has ripened for a year or more. Of course that also means a range from "mild" to "lots of character".

If you go by the typical approach of choosing cheeses, a mature gouda would be an excellent choice for a soufflé (a medium age Gouda is similar to a Guyère, but with less tang and more caramel undertones, very old Goudas show salt crystals and a flaky texture not unlike Parmesan), yet there is no reason why a younger Gouda would be "wrong" if you prefer your soufflé less "cheesy" and more "eggy".

So use your favourite recipe (or [scour the Internet](https://www.google.com/search?q=cheese%20souffle%20gouda)) and select the right Gouda for you - there is no accounting for taste.

Answer (score 0):

Gouda is popularly an ingredient in soufflés. See: https://www.google.com/search?q=gouda+souffle+recipe&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8 Many cheese soufflé recipes use hard cheese like Parmesan to prep the baking dish, to allow for the soufflé to "grab on" on its way up, and to keep the soufflé from sticking. Gouda would not be great for that, but you can certainly use it to flavor the soufflé itself.